# Why next-redux-wrapper hydrate twice in logger?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper

I am getting stuck in using next-redux-wrapper with nextjs and
I want to clarify concept between server and client about `Hydrate`.

Recently I start to learn nextjs with next-redux-wrapper and redux-toolkit packages
and I false the `reactStrictMode`, then basically complete setup with above 2 packages.
So now, I am get stuck in a redux-logger result.

WHY the `_NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE_` are logger twice ?, Is it a normal or is my code something wrong ?

```
1. redux-logger.js?  action api/config/middlewareRegistered @ 11:59:42.396
2. redux-logger.js?  action NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE @ 11:59:42.400 // Here first
2.1 index.js? undefined
3. redux-logger.js?  action api/executeQuery/pending @ 11:59:42.429
4. redux-logger.js?  action NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE @ 11:59:42.434 // Here second
4.1 index.js? undefined
5. redux-logger.js?  action api/internalSubscriptions/subscriptionsUpdated @11:59:42.444
6. redux-logger.js?  action api/executeQuery/fulfilled @ 11:59:42.707
6.1 index.js {count: 1154, next: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/? 
offset=20&limit=20', previous: null, results: Array(20)}
```

Here is my full version code if need.
[github source link](https://github.com/dc198689/nextjs-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve created a PR that is going to be merged soon that may fix this: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/pull/502. Can you try that code to see if it resolves your issue?